# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'save_frame'`

Tags: python, numpy

Below is the code:

```
 from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip
 from docx import Document
 from docx.shared import Inches
 def extract_frames_to_docx(mp4_file, output_docx, interval=1):
# Open the MP4 file
   video = VideoFileClip(mp4_file)
# Create a new Word document
    doc = Document()
# Calculate the total number of frames
   total_frames = int(video.duration * video.fps)
# Determine the frame indices to extract based on the interval
   frame_indices = range(0, total_frames, interval)
# Extract frames at specified intervals and insert them into the Word document
   for idx in frame_indices:
       frame = video.get_frame(idx / video.fps)  # Get frame at specified time
       image_path = f"frame_{idx}.png"
       frame.save_frame(image_path)  # Save the frame as an image
       doc.add_picture(image_path, width=Inches(6))  # Insert the image into the Word document
# Save the Word document
   doc.save(output_docx)
# Close the video file
   video.close()
# Example usage with an interval of 10 frames
 extract_frames_to_docx("testvideo.mp4", "video_frames1.docx", interval=10)
```

Below is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/azs92/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/zmp4todoc(reducedimages).py", line 24, in <module>
  extract_frames_to_docx("testvideo.mp4", "video_frames1.docx", interval=10)
File "C:/Users/azs92/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/zmp4todoc(reducedimages).py", line 17, in    extract_frames_to_docx
frame.save_frame(image_path)  # Save the frame as an image
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'save_frame'`
```

I was expecting this program to read a video and extract related images from it into a document.

Comment: where did you get the idea that the save_frame() function exists?

Comment: I just got it from an existing piece of code...that existed in our system...

Comment: When I look at the documentation I don't understand if it ever ran. Clearly `frame` has no method `save_frame`, but your `video` object does. Have a look at the documentation of VideoFileClip/VideoClip.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use,

```
with open("test_array","wb") as f:
      numpy.save(image_path,frame)`
```

Comment: i used numpy.save(image_path,frame) instead of frame.save_frame(image_path)...Is that what you are suggesting? If so it doesnot work

Comment: use context manager to create file object . it working for me